# Aligning items bottom in a scrollable container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a section for messages to be displayed in. I have the most recent one showing up at the bottom and they're in a fixed height container that has a scrollbar for overflow.

When there's not enough messages for the container to need to scroll, I want the messages to be aligned to the bottom of the container. I figured I could do that with `flex-direction: column` and `justify-content: flex-end`, but then it makes the container not scrollable.

[Here's a jsfiddle example of what I'm looking at.](https://jsfiddle.net/sz742f91/28/) As you can see, when the first three lines of the CSS are commented out the message box is functional but messages first appear at the top before the box fills up. When you uncomment the lines, the messages start appearing at the bottom but you can no longer scroll when it fills up.

```js
let messageScrollArea = document.getElementById('message-area');
let messageScrollArea2 = document.getElementById('message-area-2');

messageScrollArea.scroll(0, 100000);
messageScrollArea2.scroll(0, 100000);
```

```css
#message-area,
#message-area-2 {
  /* display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end; */
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.message-card {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="message-area">
    <div class="message-card">
      Test message
    </div>
    <div class="message-card">
      Test message 2
    </div>
    <div class="message-card">
      Test message 3
    </div>
    <div class="message-card">
      Test message 4
    </div>
    <div class="message-card">
      Test message 5
    </div>
    <div class="message-card">
      Test message 6
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="message-area-2">
    <div class="message-card">
      Test message
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found the answer to this css bug on github. Set `justify-content:flex-start` and then give the first item a `margin-top:auto` so it pushes the items to the bottom. See this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sz742f91/28/   The github issue is here https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs/issues/53

Comment: Thanks a lot! It looks like you linked my own fiddle, but I got the gist from the github issue.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to save the fiddle!